# Jupyter notebook and python3 not working (installed the miniconda 3.7 package)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

As the title suggests, I have installed Miniconda using for Python 3.7.  I see that I have `ipykernel` but my `jupyter-kernelspec` is still only python2.

Is there a simple way to just override this?  Also, why might this have happened even though I installed the python3 version of miniconda?

Edit: `conda info` also shows that python is version 3.7

Comment: did you activate your environment?  `conda activate env_name`

Comment: @NaqibHakimi I did.